# Finding NPSP source for TDTM_Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, npsp

I've got an error message which contains "npsp.TDTM_Opportunity: execution of AfterInsert" in it. I know the NPSP source is on [github](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP), but how can I find the source for that routine so I can see what it's doing?
When I go into NPSP > NPSP settings > System tools - trigger configuration there's a class called npsp4hub.Opportunities_TDTM, but when I search for Opportunities_TDTM in the NPSP repo it doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPSP's `TDTM_Opportunity` trigger is located [here](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/blob/main/force-app/tdtm/triggers/TDTM_Opportunity.trigger). However, as you'll see, the trigger contains no logic at all. NPSP's Table Driven Trigger Management framework delegates all logic into handler classes.

To solve this issue, you'll need to review your logs in detail to determine which TDTM handler class caused the exception. This could be one of NPSP's out-of-the-box handlers, one of your custom handlers, or a handler installed by a managed package.

The class you reference called `npsp4hub.Opportunities_TDTM` appears to belong to a third-party managed package with the namespace `npsp4hub`. The NPSP managed package uses the namespace `npsp`.

Comment: npsp4hub is the payments processing app Findock, for the record